# How to access the raw query string (or full URL) in a Chalice (AWS Lambda/API Gateway) app?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I'm using Chalice to build a fairly straightforward API on AWS Lambda & API Gateway.

I need a way to get access to the raw query string (i.e `foo=bar&abc=123`). When accessing the `app.current_request.query_params` dictionary, it's already been processed, such that any empty parameters (`foo=&bar=`) have been stripped out.

Unfortunately I'm working with a third-party API that sends a signed hash value in the query string, based off the raw query string. I can't verify it without the original, unaltered query string. Is there any way to access it other than `current_request.query_params`?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get everything you do the following.

Let's say you are hitting the route `/objects/{what}?human=you&thing=computer`

```py
@app.route('/objects', methods=['GET'])
def myobject(what):
    everything = app.current_request.to_dict()
    print("look at me: {}".format(params))
```

For more information see: [Request from the Chalice docs](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#request)

Comment: `params` is non existing variable here, did oyu mean `.format(everything)`

Comment: yes I structured it like that to match the question but I should of better explained things ... good catch